# Determining an expression for a linear function $f$ such that $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$

Tags: real-analysis

> We say that a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *linear* if it is of the form $f(t)=mt+n$ for some $m, n \in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is determined by its values at two (distinct) points in $[a,b]$. More precisely, arrive at an expression for a linear $f$ such that $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$ for some $x_1, x_2 \in [a,b]$.

I know that this function is continuous on $[a,b]$ and so it is uniformly continuous. But I don't know what they really asked for?.

Comment: I think you are being asked to find what in precalculus is taught as finding the equation for a line given two points. You are to calculate the slope and intercept from that data. There is nothing about continuity of any kind in your question.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question now after seeing the ans i feel ashamed. This question was right after the theorem that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous. So i dont understand this one.

Comment: No apology needed. Often in mathematics something looks obvious after the fact. That doesn't mean it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two equations to uniquely determine $m$ and $n$. Plugging into linear equation any two points you may arrive to an expression of the form

$$y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} (x-x_1)$$

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you meant to denote the $a,b$ delimiting the interval differently from the $a,b$ in the definition of a linear function, so that the statement makes sense.

A linear function from $R$ to $R$ is simply a (non-vertical) line, so intuitively it can of course be determined by any two points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ of the plane such that $x_1 \neq x_2$. Indeed, if $f$ is of the form $f(x) = \alpha x + \beta$, evaluting $f$ in $x_1$ and in $x_2$ yields

$$
\left \{
\begin{aligned}
\alpha x_1 + \beta = y_1 \\
\alpha x_2 + \beta = y_2
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

and as $x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct you find

$$
\alpha = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
$$

and

$$
\beta = y_1 - \alpha x_1.
$$

$\alpha$ is the slope of the line and $\beta$ is the ordinate of the point of the line at $x=0$.